# prevent sql injection plus using regexp in zend

Tags: regex, zend-framework, sql-injection, zend-db

I want to prevent sql injection as well as want to use `REGEXP` to get similar results in the same query. I know I prevent sql injection like this

```
 $this->getAdapter()->fetchAlll("SELECT * FROM $this->_table WHERE email = ? ", array($email));
```

Now I have another query in which I am using `REGEXP` to get similar results on the basis of first 3 and last three characters. My query looks like this

```
$this->_adapter->fetchAll("SELECT country_name FROM $this->_name WHERE country_name REGEXP '^$front' OR country_name REGEXP '$end$'");
```

Putting `^` in begin while using `REGEXP` means you want to compare from start and using `$` at end means you want to compare from end.

So Now I want to ask how can I write the above query to prevent sql injection as of the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
$query = "SELECT country_name
              FROM $this->_name
          WHERE country_name REGEXP ? OR
                country_name REGEXP ?";
$this->_adapter->fetchAll($query, array('^'.$front, $end.'$'));
```